# Drawing on an external image with Asymptote

Tags: graphics, asymptote

When embedding Asymptote code in LaTeX with the `asy` environment, is there a method to include an external image and add some labels, boxes, or arrows on the image, just like what the Tikz can do ([Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz))? Is it possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Yes it should be possible, but I am not sure what you are tying to do that is not already answered in the question you linked to.  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that shows what you have tired so far and tell us what specific problems you are having with it.

Comment: With no MWE, I don't see we can tackle this, so I've closed as 'not a real question'.

Comment: This question is about asymptote, not tikz; it just mentions tikz to show what the OP wanted.  How is this not a real question?

Comment: Since the question was asked, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129801/484) has been added to the TikZ question showing how to use Asymptote instead.